# What is the/any Arminian/Catholic interpretation of Hebrews 10:14?

Tags: catholicism, soteriology, arminianism, sanctification, perseverance-of-saints

Hebrews 10:14 reads:

> For by one offering he has perfected for all time those who are being
>   sanctified.

How do Christians who believe that salvation can be lost interpret this verse? I hear lots of Reformed people using it, but in all the commentaries I've read the subject isn't really addressed, so I don't know.

Comment: Should this be split into two questions? Arminians and Catholics are likely to offer differing support for their beliefs.

Comment: I was meaning this with specific regard to losing salvation, so either position answering would've sufficed, but you could be right. If you still want me to change it I can adjust it to just Catholic, or you can if that's how it works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In paragraph 480 of St. Thomas Aquinas' [Commentary on the Epistle to the Hebrews](http://dhspriory.org/thomas/SSHebrews.htm#101), he explains that the way sacrifice was done in the past was to wipe out past sins. The people sinned, and then a priest offered an animal sacrifice in reparation for those sins. This verse states that by Christ's one sacrifice, past and future sins are being accounted for, thus encompassing 'all those being sanctified.' This may seem in contradiction to Catholicism, because we offer the sacrifice of the mass every day. However, Aquinas contests that this sacrifice is no different than the very one that Christ offered, re-presented in a non-bloody form.

So in summary, Christ dying on the cross was enough to perfect all those seeking sanctification, but we have to choose to participate in that sacrifice, it is not just handed out to those who turn their back on God.